# Daily python data to weekly via pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I want to take a CSV that shows daily data and create a new sheet that includes the same data in a weekly view.

Currently I have:

```
#import required libraries
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
#read the daily data file
looker_data = pd.read_csv("jan21_looker_upload.csv")
#convert date column into datetime object
looker_data['Date'] = looker_data['Date'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
#convert daily data to weekly
weekly_data = looker_data.groupby("URL").resample('W-Mon', label='right', closed='right', on='Date').sum().reset_index().sort_values(by='Date')
##Export in Excel
weekly_data.to_excel("jan21-looker.xlsx")
```

The code works but removes specific data points that I would like to keep in the new view. For reference, The existing CSV looks something like this:

```
Date    | URL          | Sessions  | Conversions
1/14/21 | example.com/ | 110333.   | 330
```

But when I run the code I get:

```
URL          | Date    | Conversions
example.com/ | 1/14/21 | 330
```

Is there something I am missing that will help me take the output include all data in a weekly view? All help is appreciated!

Comment: Check `looker_data['Sessions'].dtype`. It's likely to be `object` so it is excluded from `groupby().sum()`. You may  want to do `pd.to_numeric`

Comment: @QuangHoang I had a feeling it was something simple. Really appreciate the quick response! I got everything I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- synthesized data you note
- resampled in same way
- additionally put column order back in place by final `loc[]`

```
d = pd.date_range(dt.date(2021,1,20), "today")
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Date":d,
    "URL":np.random.choice(["example.com/","google.com/","bigbank.com/"],len(d)),
    "Sessions": np.random.randint(3000, 300000, len(d)),
    "Conversations": np.random.randint(200, 500, len(d))
             })

dfw = (df.groupby("URL").resample('W-Mon', label='right', closed='right', on='Date').sum()
 # cleanup - index as columns, order or row & columns
 .reset_index().sort_values("Date").loc[:,df.columns]
)
```

|  | Date | URL | Sessions | Conversations |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-01-25 00:00:00 | bigbank.com/ | 187643 | 226 |
| 4 | 2021-01-25 00:00:00 | example.com/ | 454543 | 966 |
| 7 | 2021-01-25 00:00:00 | google.com/ | 143307 | 574 |
| 1 | 2021-02-01 00:00:00 | bigbank.com/ | 335614 | 904 |
| 5 | 2021-02-01 00:00:00 | example.com/ | 260055 | 623 |
| 8 | 2021-02-01 00:00:00 | google.com/ | 396096 | 866 |
| 2 | 2021-02-08 00:00:00 | bigbank.com/ | 743231 | 1143 |
| 6 | 2021-02-08 00:00:00 | example.com/ | 562073 | 1206 |
| 9 | 2021-02-08 00:00:00 | google.com/ | 229929 | 472 |
| 3 | 2021-02-15 00:00:00 | bigbank.com/ | 327898 | 747 |